# 'MULTIPLE_VALIDATIONS_FAILED' Error when ceating Linkedin campaign

Tags: php, curl, linkedin-api

I'm trying to create campaign using linkedin campaign API 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignsV2'.
When Trying to create campaign for United Kingdom it throws error:
`Multiple errors occurred during the input validation. Please see errorDetails for more information` and when I check errorDetails it says :

GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignsV2` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"errorDetailType":"com.linkedin.common.error.BadRequest","code":"MULTIPLE_VALIDATIONS_FAILED","message":"Multiple error (truncated...)

My payload is :

```
$formData = [
    "account" => "XXXXXXX",
    "campaignGroup" => "urn:li:sponsoredCampaignGroup:XXXXXXX",
    "audienceExpansionEnabled" => false,
    "costType" => "CPC",
    "creativeSelection" => "OPTIMIZED",
    "totalBudget" => [
        "amount" => "51.00",
        "currencyCode" => "GBP"
    ],
    "locale" => [
        "country" => "GB",
        "language" => "en"
    ],
    "name" => "Testing Campaign Name",
    "offsiteDeliveryEnabled" => false,
    "runSchedule" => [
        "end" => 1690022880000,
        "start" => 1689850080000,
    ],
    "targetingCriteria" => [
        "include" => [
            "and" => [
                [
                    "or" => [
                        "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:locations" => [
                            "urn:li:geo:101165590"
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "type" => "SPONSORED_UPDATES",
    "unitCost" => [
        "amount" => "2.00",
        "currencyCode" => "GBP"
    ],
    "status" => "ACTIVE"
];
```

When I set "country" => "GB" to "country" => "US" or "country" => "CN", So campaign successfully created but in case of "GB" it throws error. why?
However the Ads account created in United kingdom.
Please let me know if you know something about it. Thank you.

why getting 'MULTIPLE_VALIDATIONS_FAILED' error.

Comment: What does `errorDetails` say?

Comment: It says 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignsV2` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"errorDetailType":"com.linkedin.common.error.BadRequest","code":"MULTIPLE_VALIDATIONS_FAILED","message":"Multiple error (truncated...)'

Comment: The interesting part is cut off.